# Random Number Range in Python, ValueError: empty for Range ()

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

This python code is returning a `ValueError` in the random number generator section of the code. I ran it with hardcoded values in the function: `def fermat_test(n):` at line 
`a = random.randit(2,n-1)`, and it seemed to run otherwise. I can't figure out why the range is out of bounds?

```
import random
def remainder(i,j):
    rem = i%j
    return rem
def is_even(n): return n % 2 == 0
def square(n): return n**2
def expmod(b, e, m):
    if e==0:
        return 1
    elif is_even(e):
        expm = expmod(b, e/2,m)
        return remainder(expm*expm,m)
    else:
     return remainder(b*expmod(b,e-1,m),m)
def fermat_test(n):
    a = random.randint(2,n-1)
    return expmod(a,n,n)==a
def is_fermat_prime(n, ntimes):
 if ntimes == 0:
     return True
 elif fermat_test(n):
    return is_fermat_prime(n,ntimes-1)
 else:
     return False
## this is the test you can use to test your code
def sum_of_fermat_primes(n):
 sum = 0
 for i in xrange(n+1):
     if is_fermat_prime(i, 70):
         sum += i
 return sum
print sum_of_fermat_primes(10)
print sum_of_fermat_primes(20)
print sum_of_fermat_primes(560)
print sum_of_fermat_primes(570)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Terik\.atom\code.py", line 33, in <module>
    print sum_of_fermat_primes(10)
  File "C:\Users\Terik\.atom\code.py", line 30, in sum_of_fermat_primes
    if is_fermat_prime(i, 70):
  File "C:\Users\Terik\.atom\code.py", line 22, in is_fermat_prime
    elif fermat_test(n):
  File "C:\Users\Terik\.atom\code.py", line 17, in fermat_test
    a = random.randint(2,n-1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 242, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 218, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (2,0, -2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because in

```
a = random.randint(2,n-1)
```

`n - 1` is less than `2`. In fact, the value of `n` comes from `i` in `for i in xrange(n+1)`, so it starts from `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. These smallest values make the `random.randint(2,n-1)` invalid.

Comment: `for i in xrange(3,n+1):` based on what @Yu Hao said, I found this worked. Though I'm not sure your code detects Fermat primes correctly.

Comment: @rofls, Yes, I see that it worked for me as well. Why do you feel that it is incorrect?

Comment: Your function says 7 is Fermat and Wolfram says it's not:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html

Comment: Oh I see! There's some confusion there. I am using Fermat's Little Theorem to compute primes, not just finding Fermat's primes, if that makes sense. So my purpose IS to add all primes, just using his theory.

Comment: Aah ok that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your i in xrange starts at 0 it should start at 1 instead.

```
for i in xrange(1, n+1):
```